# How to resolve a type error in javascript/cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am learning cypress and javascript and have come across this type error.

```
 TypeError: _testElements.default.selectionRow is not a function
```

I looked at some documentation with cypress and can't see a mistake I am making in the code, so was hoping someone with javascript and cypress experience may know why this error is being outputted.

Code:

First the class where it gets the element:

```
class testElements {

    selectionRow() {
        return cy.get('.selectionRow')
     }

    typeButton() {
        return cy.get('.typeButton')
     }
 
  
}

export default testElements
```

And then the code it's referring the error to is below:

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import testElements from '../elements/testElements';

When ("User selects a row", () => {
  testElements.selectionRow()
  .within(() => {
    testElements.typeButton().not(".disabled");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a class instance to use the methods:

```
const testElem = new testElements();
testElem.selectionRow()
```

And I suggest to use uppercase name convention for class `TestElements`.

If you don't want to instantiating the class, you can use [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#static_methods_and_properties)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much :) I do have another question which I will post the link. It's to do with the within() in cypress and just need some understanding on it from a code point of view as it's so different to what I'm use to :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131123/using-the-cypress-within-and-if-it-selects-correct-element-based-on-condition